# PyQt - Radiobuttons not checkable

Tags: python, radio-button, pyqt

I want to display the result of an SQL query with radio buttons. For this purpose, I use an array of radiobuttons. This works fine, it displays what I want. The problem I have is that the buttons are not "checkable". If I click on them, nothing happens. I'm sure it is a stupid mistake, but I can't see what's wrong.

Here is my code :

```
groups = select.getGroups(self.parent.db) #This returns a list of strings
self.groupList = {}
self.groupBtn = []
i = 0
radioLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
radioGroup = QtGui.QGroupBox()
for g in groups:
      self.groupList[g[0]] = i
      name = g[0]
      self.groupBtn.append(QtGui.QRadioButton(name))
      radioLayout.addWidget(self.groupBtn[i])
      i = i+1

radioGroup.setLayout(radioLayout)
self.groupBtn[0].setChecked(True)
self.groupLayout.addWidget(radioGroup)
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing ?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click on the buttons?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you post a complete program that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Ditto, the code works for me in its basic form. Can you show more?

Answer (score 0):

1. "Radio buttons typically present the user with a "one of many" choice. In a group of radio buttons only one radio button at a time can be checked; if the user selects another button, the previously selected button is switched off."
2. If that is not your desired behaviour, you may consider using check buttons (QCheckButton). If it is:
3. You need to be sure that you have not incidentally set `setAutoExclusive(false)` somewhere in code, for any of those radio buttons (by default it is set on true).
4. Last thing I can suggest (based on the code that you have shown): Try to put radio buttons  in QButtonGroup() instead of QGroupBox().